# Pandas- repeat dataframe columns based on a reference dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to rename and repeat my dataframe columns based on a reference dict. Below I have created a dummy dataframe:

```
rawdata= {'id':['json','molly','tina','jake','molly'],'entity':['present','absent','absent','present','present'],'entity2':['present','present','present','absent','absent'],'entity3':['absent','absent','absent','present','absent']}
df= pd.DataFrame(rawdata)
df.set_index('id')

        entity  entity2  entity3
id                              
json   present  present   absent
molly   absent  present   absent
tina    absent  present   absent
jake   present   absent  present
molly  present   absent   absent
```

Now I have the following example dict:

```
ref_dict= {'entity':['entity_exp1'],'entity2':['entity2_exp1','entity2_exp2'],'entity3':['entity3_exp1','entity3_exp2','entity3_exp3']}
```

I need to now replace the column names based on dict values and if a column has more than one value than the column should be repeated. Following is my desired dataframe:

```
       entity_exp1  entity2_exp1 entity2_exp2 entity3_exp1 entity3_exp2 entity3_exp3
id                      
json    present      present      present      absent      absent    absent
molly   absent       present      present      absent      absent    absent
tina    absent       present      present      absent      absent    absent
jake    present      absent       absent       present     present   present
molly   present      absent       absent       absent      absent    absent
```

Comment: Thank you for excepting my answer. Feel free to vote the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. You always have most amazing solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.concat` on a dictionary comprehension

```
pd.concat({k: df[v] for v, l in ref_dict.items() for k in l}, axis=1)

      entity2_exp1 entity2_exp2 entity3_exp1 entity3_exp2 entity3_exp3 entity_exp1
id                                                                                
json       present      present       absent       absent       absent     present
molly      present      present       absent       absent       absent      absent
tina       present      present       absent       absent       absent      absent
jake        absent       absent      present      present      present     present
molly       absent       absent       absent       absent       absent     present
```

**Option 2**
Slice the dataframe and rename columns

```
repeats = df.columns.map(lambda x: len(ref_dict[x]))
d1 = df.reindex_axis(df.columns.repeat(repeats), 1)
d1.columns = df.columns.map(ref_dict.get).values.sum()
d1

      entity_exp1 entity2_exp1 entity2_exp2 entity3_exp1 entity3_exp2 entity3_exp3
id                                                                                
json      present      present      present       absent       absent       absent
molly      absent      present      present       absent       absent       absent
tina       absent      present      present       absent       absent       absent
jake      present       absent       absent      present      present      present
molly     present       absent       absent       absent       absent       absent
```

Answer (score 0):

For each column in `df` you can look for number of new column in `ref_dict` and create `new column` for them and finally, delete the old ones. You can try following:

```
# for key, value in ref_dict where old column and new columns are 
for old_column,new_columns in ref_dict.items():
    for new_column in new_columns:  # for each new_column in new_columns defined
        df[new_column] = df[old_column] # the content remains same as old column
    del df[old_column]  # now remove the old column
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop:

```
rawdata= {'id':['json','molly','tina','jake','molly'],
          'entity':['present','absent','absent','present','present'],
          'entity2':['present','present','present','absent','absent'],
          'entity3':['absent','absent','absent','present','absent']}
df= pd.DataFrame(rawdata)
df.set_index('id')
ref_dict= {'entity':['entity_exp1'],
           'entity2':['entity2_exp1','entity2_exp2'],
           'entity3':['entity3_exp1','entity3_exp2','entity3_exp3']}

# here comes the new part:
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for key, val in sorted(ref_dict.items()):
    for subval in val:
        df2[subval] = df[key]

df2['id'] = df['id']
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)

print(df2)
      entity_exp1 entity2_exp1 entity2_exp2 entity3_exp1 entity3_exp2  entity3_exp3  
id                                                                      
json      present      present      present       absent       absent        absent   
molly      absent      present      present       absent       absent        absent   
tina       absent      present      present       absent       absent        absent   
jake      present       absent       absent      present      present       present    
molly     present       absent       absent       absent       absent        absent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex your df using the dict key as column names and then rename the columns using values of the dict.

```
df_new = df.reindex(columns=sum([[k]*len(v) for k,v in ref_dict.items()],[]))
df_new.columns=sum(ref_dict.values(),[])
df_new
Out[573]: 
  entity_exp1 entity2_exp1 entity2_exp2 entity3_exp1 entity3_exp2 entity3_exp3
0     present      present      present       absent       absent       absent
1      absent      present      present       absent       absent       absent
2      absent      present      present       absent       absent       absent
3     present       absent       absent      present      present      present
4     present       absent       absent       absent       absent       absent
```